# Create Cloud watch alarm using terraform and send notification on alarm hit

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

> Creating a cloudwatch alarm using Terraform but stucked with error 
>   parse error at 1:20: expected "}" but found invalid sequence "$" ,
>    how can pass multiple variables inside dimensions  & alarm_actions

```
variable "sfn_name"         { }
variable "sns_topic"        { }

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "checkQueueLength" {
  alarm_name = "MonitorQueueLength"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods = "1"
  metric_name = "ExecutionsStarted"
  namespace = "AWS/States"
  period = "2"
  statistic = "Sum"
  threshold = "1"
  dimensions {
    StateMachineArn = "${aws_sfn_activity.${var.sfn_name}.arn}"
    alarm_description = "checkStatesQueueLength"
    actions_enabled = "true"
  }
  alarm_actions = ["${aws_sns_topic.${var.sns_topic}.arn}"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't. Instead you would pass in the aws_sfn_activity and sns topic arn.

```
variable "sfn_arn"         { }
variable "sns_topic_arn"        { }

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "checkQueueLength" {
  alarm_name = "MonitorQueueLength"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods = "1"
  metric_name = "ExecutionsStarted"
  namespace = "AWS/States"
  period = "2"
  statistic = "Sum"
  threshold = "1"
  dimensions {
    StateMachineArn = "${var.sfn_arn}"
    alarm_description = "checkStatesQueueLength"
    actions_enabled = "true"
  }
  alarm_actions = ["${var.sns_topic_arn}"]
}
```